# Get remote file size using URL in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get image size using

```
get_headers($url)
```

But I am getting warning like

```
get_headers() [function.get-headers]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in
```

Is there any other way to Do so?

Thanks.

Comment: You could issue a `HEAD` request and look for the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: http://dzone.com/snippets/get-remote-filesize-http-head

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `curl_getinfo()` function to get the remote file size.

```
 $ch = curl_init('http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

 curl_close($ch);
 echo $size;
```

Answer (score 9):

You must perform a HEAD request. This will tell the server that you're only interested in the HTTP headers.

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com');
```

This will return an array of headers. You must find the content-length item which has the file size (number of bytes).

Comment: Nice answer, thanks dude