# How to show file size when force the browser to download in PHP

Tags: php, download

I'm downloading mp4,mp3 etc.. files from my server with php. But browsers are not showing the size of file.
I searched everywhere but i couldn't find any working answer. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

**Here is the code** :

```
  function force_download($file)
 {
 $ext = explode(".", $file);
 switch($ext[sizeof($ext)-1])
{
  case 'jar': $mime = "application/java-archive"; break;
  case 'zip': $mime = "application/zip"; break;
  case 'jpeg': $mime = "image/jpeg"; break;
  case 'jpg': $mime = "image/jpg"; break;
  case 'jad': $mime = "text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor"; break;
  case "gif": $mime = "image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $mime = "image/png"; break;
  case "pdf": $mime = "application/pdf"; break;
  case "txt": $mime = "text/plain"; break;
  case "doc": $mime = "application/msword"; break;
  case "ppt": $mime = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  case "wbmp": $mime = "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"; break;
  case "wmlc": $mime = "application/vnd.wap.wmlc"; break;
  case "mp4s": $mime = "application/mp4"; break;
  case "ogg": $mime = "application/ogg"; break;
  case "pls": $mime = "application/pls+xml"; break;
  case "asf": $mime = "application/vnd.ms-asf"; break;
  case "swf": $mime = "application/x-shockwave-flash"; break;
  case "mp4": $mime = "video/mp4"; break;
  case "m4a": $mime = "audio/mp4"; break;
  case "m4p": $mime = "audio/mp4"; break;
  case "mp4a": $mime = "audio/mp4"; break;
  case "mp3": $mime = "audio/mpeg"; break;
  case "m3a": $mime = "audio/mpeg"; break;
  case "m2a": $mime = "audio/mpeg"; break;
  case "mp2a": $mime = "audio/mpeg"; break;
  case "mp2": $mime = "audio/mpeg"; break;
  case "mpga": $mime = "audio/mpeg"; break;
  case "wav": $mime = "audio/wav"; break;
  case "m3u": $mime = "audio/x-mpegurl"; break;
  case "bmp": $mime = "image/bmp"; break;
  case "ico": $mime = "image/x-icon"; break;
  case "3gp": $mime = "video/3gpp"; break;
  case "3g2": $mime = "video/3gpp2"; break;
  case "mp4v": $mime = "video/mp4"; break;
  case "mpg4": $mime = "video/mp4"; break;
  case "m2v": $mime = "video/mpeg"; break;
  case "m1v": $mime = "video/mpeg"; break;
  case "mpe": $mime = "video/mpeg"; break;
  case "mpeg": $mime = "video/mpeg"; break;
  case "mpg": $mime = "video/mpeg"; break;
  case "mov": $mime = "video/quicktime"; break;
  case "qt": $mime = "video/quicktime"; break;
  case "avi": $mime = "video/x-msvideo"; break;
  case "midi": $mime = "audio/midi"; break;
  case "mid": $mime = "audio/mid"; break;
  case "amr": $mime = "audio/amr"; break;
  default: $mime = "application/force-download";
 }
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();

 readfile($file);
}   

if (isset($_POST['downl'])){
$file = "http://localhost/project1/downloads/gmf.mp4";
force_download($file); 

}
<form  method="POST" action=''>
    <?php echo'<input type="submit" name="downl"  value="Download Baby" >' ;    ?>
</form>
```

**If i try to show file size with** `echo filesize($file)` **it gives this error :**

```
 Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://localhost/project1/downloads...
```

Comment: $file, should not be a URI, it should be the local file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since php 5.0.0 the `file` command supports [http wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) but the http wrapper does not support stat commands like size. So you cannot get the file size in your case with size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so how can i get file size and download file ? any idea ?

Comment: There are [various answers on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073406/get-remote-file-size-using-url-in-php).