# Can I avoid using ini setting upload_max_filesize in order to detect file size before upload to the server?

Tags: php

Currently I am using in PHPH ini setting upload_max_filesize to define deny fiel upload over a specific amount.

This solution works but it is global.

I would like to know if it is possible in PHP to detect file size (without using JS on the client) and abort the request before the actual file upload is completed on the server (so I can save some bandwidth).

PS: I can also use a library for this task.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1122443/4916265

Comment: Check this post here, for testing a remote-file-size on server side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073406/get-remote-file-size-using-url-in-php

Comment: And have to note that: you have to do something with JS on the client side, if you want to prevent the upload if the file is too large.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing upload\_max\_filesize on PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)